# Save a list as txt file with comma and remove duplicates

Tags: python, list

How can I save the following list to a txt file.

```
col_list = [['AAPL'], ['AMZN'], ['COP'], ['COP'], ['COP']]
```

output.txt should be:
AAPL,AMZN,COP

Comment:  Homework alert. Can you please explain what you have tried thus far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to convert every element of `col_list` into a string

```
col_list = [['AAPL'], ['AMZN'], ['COP'], ['COP'], ['COP']]
new_list = list(col_list[i][0] for i in range(len(col_list)))
# ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'COP', 'COP', 'COP']
```

Second, remove the duplicate value with `set` and `list`

```
new_list1 = list(set(new_list)) # ['AMZN', 'AAPL', 'COP']
```

Then you write each element of the final list into a file, with the comma after, except the last element

```
with open('output.txt', 'w+') as f:
    i = 0
    while i < len(new_list1)-1:
        f.write(new_list1[i])
        f.write(',')
        i = i+1
    f.write(new_list1[-1])
#AMZN,AAPL,COP
```

If each element of the first list has multiplier values, like `col_list = [['AAPL, 'AAA'], ['AMZN'], ['COP', 'ZZZZ']]`. You could extract the string with two loops, 1 loop running through each ele in the outside list and 1 loop through each ele in the inside list

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to flatten your input list,

```
In [1]: [j for i in col_list for j in i]
Out[1]: ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'COP', 'COP', 'COP']
```

Then remove the duplicates using `set` and write them into a file. The code will look like this,

```
col_set = set([j for i in col_list for j in i])
with open('Output.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(','.join(col_set))
```